# NGINX: proxy_pass microservices

Tags: nginx, apache-zookeeper, mesos, marathon

I have a `mesos` cluster working in environment test and I set up `nginx + nixy` for service discovery. It is working fine, but when `nginx` make a `proxy_pass` for `docker` container, I receive a `404 error`.

ex: I have a `Tomcat` container listen in `privateip:37130`, if I configure `proxy_pass` for location `/`, it is working! If i configure for location `/service`, I get the `404 error` code.

Someone have any idea?

My `nginx.conf`

```
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    use epoll;
    worker_connections 2048;
    multi_accept on;
}
http {
    add_header X-Proxy  always;
    access_log off;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
    server_tokens off;
    client_max_body_size 128m;
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_buffers 4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    proxy_redirect off;
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        ''  close;
    }
    # time out settings
    proxy_send_timeout 120;
    proxy_read_timeout 120;
    send_timeout 120;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
    upstream tomcat {
        server 172.30.119.214:31816;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name app.org;

        location / {
            return 503;
        }
        location /tomcat/ {
            proxy_set_header HOST $host;
            proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
            proxy_connect_timeout 30;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_pass http://tomcat;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change below

```
proxy_pass http://tomcat;
```

to

```
proxy_pass http://tomcat/;
```

Adding the trailing `/` would make sure that the `/tomcat/` from the location will not be sent to the tomcat service

Comment: Great, do accept it as the answer by clicking the tick button near upvotes